# shared ResNet block in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build a shared resnet block in keras but I don't know how to assign the down sample to the block

```
def SharedResBlock(filters, kernelSizel, downSample):
    x1 = Conv2D(filters, kernelSizel, padding="same",
           activation="relu", strides=(1 if not downSample else 4))
    x2 = Conv2D(filters, kernelSizel, padding="same")
    if downSample:
        input = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernelSizel, strides=4, padding="same")
    x3 = Add()
    return x3
input_A = Input(shape=(64, 64), name="iA")
input_B = Input(shape=(64, 64), name="iB")
shared = Conv2D(16, 5, strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")
for i in range(1, 19):
    if i%2 == 0:
        cnt+=1
    convPA = SheredResBlock(convPA, filterSize[min(cnt,len(filterSize)-1)],3,(1 if i%2==0 else 0))
    convPB = SheredResBlock(convPB, filterSize[min(cnt,len(filterSize)-1)],3,(1 if i%2==0 else 0))
```

This won't work and creates two different blocks, I was wondering How I can fix it

Comment: Where are you calling `SharedResBlock`?

Comment: @erip my bad Updated